# how to get Auth Token in fb by providing emailId and password?

Tags: java, facebook, token, restfb

I am developing some small app so the requirement is on the login page user is prompted to enter his fb email id and password and in the response my application will get auth token and his node_id so that I can perform further action. How to do this? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The purpose of token-based authentication systems is that users should never have to provide their password to your site, which would give you unlimited access to their account. Instead, you use a JS authentication system which lets the user confirm the access they want to give you simply by being logged in on Facebook itself.

Comment: oh yes, apologies I never thought of this fact